# Possible bug with URLRead

Tags: web-access

Version 11 introduces `URLRead` (and others) to replace `URLFetch`, but I have run into a strange problem while trying to switch to the new function.

These two both work:

```
URLFetch["http://www.nottingham.ac.uk/physics/"]
URLRead["http://www.nottingham.ac.uk/physics/"]
```

But whereas

```
URLFetch["http://www.nottingham.ac.uk/~ppzphy/"]
```

successfully loads another page on the same server, this one

```
URLRead["http://www.nottingham.ac.uk/~ppzphy/"]
```

gives a 404 error (on my machine, running Mathematica 11.0 on Windows 7).

I had suspected that the problem was the `~` in the second URL, but replacing it by `%7E` does not work, and other pages with `~` can be loaded:

```
URLRead["https://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/tilde.html"]
```

Other functions such as `Import` work fine with these addresses.

---

**Update** to summarize the answers: This seems to be a combination of a problem with the server setup, so that `~` and `%7E` are treated as distinct, and inconsistent `URLEncode`-ing behavior of `URLRead`.

Comment: I can't reproduce the error. Both `URLFetch` and `URLRead` works. (Fetch returns the page, Read returns 200-OK, clicking the green button shows the exact same redirect page source) (Mathematica 11.0 from EU/Hungary)

Comment: 404 here. Win10 V11.

Comment: 404 here as well.  MacOS 10.12.2, MMA v.11.0.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't know how to automatically avoid that but it seems that everything which is considered `"Path"` or `"Query"` part of the url is automatically `URLEncoded`.

This works on Windows:

```
URLRead[<|"Scheme" -> "http", "Domain" -> "www.nottingham.ac.uk/~ppzphy/"|>, "Content"]
```

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN\">
<html>
<head>
<title>Your Page Title</title>
<meta http-equiv=\"REFRESH\" \
content=\"0;url=http://www.nottingham.ac.uk/physics/\"></HEAD>
<BODY>
Redirecting to<br><br>
<a href=\"http://www.nottingham.ac.uk/physics/\">http://www.\
nottingham.ac.uk/physics/</a>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Answer (score 4):

This is an incomplete answer, but it should help. I can reproduce on Windows 7. Using [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) it is easy to see that `URLFetch` issues this request:

```
GET /~ppzphy/ HTTP/1.1
```

while `URLRead` issues a this one:

```
GET /%7Eppzphy/ HTTP/1.1
```

Unfortunately, I didn't find a way to make URLRead work for that address.

Comment: Thanks, that's helpful. `URLFetch["http://www.nottingham.ac.uk/%7Eppzphy/"]` returns the 404 error page.

Comment: A little off-topic, but opening `http://www.nottingham.ac.uk/%7Eppzphy/` in Chrome and IE works correctly, but Firefox gives the 404 page. I think this is a problem with the way the server is set up.

Answer (score 3):

It seems like building the URL like so helps:

```
URLRead[
 HTTPRequest[
  URL["http://www.nottingham.ac.uk"], 
  <|"Path" -> "~ppzphy/"|>
 ]
]
```

This appears to avoid having `URLEncode` interfere.

Comment: BTW, I would still report this to support@wolfram.com.  At the very least its something they should be aware of.

Comment: Actually one could well argument that the problem is on the server side which to my understanding should be able to answer both cases ("~" should be escaped according to RFC1738 but the newer RFC2396 classifies it as an "unreserved" character which may or may not be escaped). The real problem on the Mathematica side for me seems to be that it doesn't behave consistently on different plattforms...